# TRESTExecutionThread FatalException does not get exception for 'no connection'

Tags: android, rest, c++builder

I have an ExecuteAsync implementation which works normally great, but won't pass an Exception to FatalException variable when the device go offline. This causes unexpected behaviour in form that a TFDMemTable won't be repopulated, just keeping the old data, nor will it clear those data when the connection go offline.

Anyone else having trouble detecting off-line situations, or do anyone have a suggestion detecting off-lined connection ?

Comment: A thread's `FatalException` property is populated only when its `Execute ()` method exits due to an *uncaught* exception. Perhaps the thread is catching the offline exception and then exiting from `Execute()` gracefully. When calling `ExecuteAsync()` it has an optional `ACompletionHandlerWithError` parameter. Is that handler being called when the thread fails?

Comment: Well...didn't think of that as an option. I see there are very few examples how to use this handler. I will surely try it out. At the moment I solved the off-lined situation by changing a 'update' column in my TFDMEMTABLE    database which is 'static' true from the TRESTRequest request and set false before I launches the ExecuteAsync function. Normally a failed request (offlined) completes far quicker than a normally or timed out request.

Comment: Sadly it seems that the function you mention is only present in Berlin, not in XE8/Appmethod 1.17...  I will try this when I (can afford) to Upgrade to Berlin...